# How to use solve_ivp with sobol analysis for parameter sensitivity (in Python)?

Tags: python

I am conducting sensitivity analysis using the Sobol and SALib tools in Python. My parameters are currently randomized between zero and one (I'm not sure what parameter values I will have yet, but they will likely change) and I am using solve_ivp to solve my system of 6 ODEs. I then want to use Sobol analysis on my solution to show which parameters have the most effect.

I initially used ODEINT and it returned nan for all of my parameters. It was recommended I use solve_ivp to get rid of this stiffness but I'm not sure how to initialize it correctly using the Sobol analysis.

You will see my code below.

```
from scipy import integrate as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import SALib
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
%matplotlib inline

def M(C,phi,chi):
    return (phi*C)/(chi+C)

def H(A,epsilon,eta):
    return epsilon+((eta*(A**n)/((A**n)+1)))

#Z[0]=X, Z[1]=Y, Z[2]=C1, Z[3]=C2, Z[4]=A1, Z[5]=A2

def dualchamber(time,Z,phi1,phi2,chi1,chi2,nu1,nu2,delta,kappa, 
                epsilon1,epsilon2,eta1,eta2,xi1,xi2,omega,rho,zeta,psi):
    dZdt = [(M(Z[2],phi1,chi1)*Z[0])-(nu1*Z[0]),
            (M(Z[3],phi2,chi2)*Z[1])-(nu2*Z[1]),
            (-M(Z[2],phi1,chi1)*Z[0])+delta-Z[2]+(Z[3]/kappa),
            (-M(Z[3],phi2,chi2)*Z[1])+delta-Z[3]+(kappa*Z[2]),
            (H(Z[4],epsilon1,eta1)*xi1*Z[0])-(omega*Z[4])-(rho*Z[4])+((zeta/psi)*Z[5]),
            (H(Z[5],epsilon2,eta2)*xi2*Z[1])-(omega*Z[5])-(rho*Z[5])+(zeta*psi*Z[4])]
    return dZdt

time=np.linspace(0,100,100)

Zinitial = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

n=2.2
phi1 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
phi2 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
chi1 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
chi2 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
nu1 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
nu2 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
delta = np.random.uniform(0,1)
kappa = np.random.uniform(0,1)
epsilon1 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
epsilon2 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
eta1 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
eta2 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
xi1 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
xi2 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
omega = np.random.uniform(0,1)
rho = np.random.uniform(0,1)
zeta = np.random.uniform(0,1)
psi = np.random.uniform(0,1)
#print(phi1,phi2,chi1,chi2,nu1,nu2,delta,kappa,epsilon1,
      #epsilon2,eta1,eta2,xi1,xi2,omega,rho,zeta,psi)

sol = solve_ivp(lambda time, Z: dualchamber(time,Z,phi1,phi2,chi1,chi2,nu1,nu2,delta,kappa, 
                epsilon1,epsilon2,eta1,eta2,xi1,xi2,omega,rho,zeta,psi),
               [time[0],time[-1]], Zinitial, t_eval=time)

problem = {
  'num_vars': 24,
  'names': ['phi1', 'phi2','chi1','chi2','nu1','nu2','delta','kappa',
            'eps1', 'eps2', 'eta1', 'eta2', 'xi1', 'xi2','o', 
            'r', 'zeta', 'psi', 'X_0', 'Y_0', 'C1_0', 'C2_0', 'A1_0', 'A2_0'],
  'bounds': [[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],
            [0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],
            [0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],
            [0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],
            [0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],
            [0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1],[0.0001,1]]
}

vals = saltelli.sample(problem, 1000, calc_second_order=True)

Y = np.zeros([vals.shape[0]])

for i in range(len(vals)):
    Y[i][:] = solve_ivp(dualchamber(time,[vals[i][18],vals[i][19],vals[i][20],vals[i][21], vals[i][22],
      vals[i][23]],vals[i][0],vals[i][1],vals[i][2],vals[i][3],vals[i][4],vals[i][5], vals[i][6],
      vals[i][7],vals[i][8],vals[i][9],vals[i][10],vals[i][11], vals[i][12],vals[i][13],vals[i][14],vals[i][15],
      vals[i][16],vals[i][17]),[time[0],time[-1]], Zinitial)[len(sol)-1]

print('\n\n====X Sobol output====\n\n')
Si_X = sobol.analyze(problem, Y[:,0], print_to_console=True)
print('\n\n====Y Sobol output====\n\n')
Si_Y = sobol.analyze(problem, Y[:,1], print_to_console=True)
print('\n\n====C1 Sobol output====\n\n')
Si_C1 = sobol.analyze(problem, Y[:,2], print_to_console=True)
print('\n\n====C2 Sobol output====\n\n')
Si_C2 = sobol.analyze(problem, Y[:,3], print_to_console=True)
print('\n\n====A1 Sobol output====\n\n')
Si_A1 = sobol.analyze(problem, Y[:,4], print_to_console=True)
print('\n\n====A2 Sobol output====\n\n')
Si_A2 = sobol.analyze(problem, Y[:,5], print_to_console=True)
```

Any help would be great. I really appreciate any feedback.
Thanks.